# Editable UITableViewCell having a left-aligned label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am very new to iphone application development and am struggling to create a table view page where each row contains a left-aligned label with an editable text next to it - just like how it works in the email account details page in the settings application on my iphone.

I have been googling the subject for hours and it is now somehow clear to me that I need to add UITextFields to UITableViewCells, but it is still not at all clear to me how I make these text fields take up the right amount of space:

- How do I make the text fields align above each other?
- How do I make the text fields expand as far as possible to the right?
- How do I prevent the text fields from hiding part of the left-aligned label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Apple Docs on Tableviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) there are a number of predefined table cells. Also look at the [Tableview programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1). Pick the one that has the font characteristics that you want and Apple will take care of it for you. Also, in the Settings app, the settings are a Grouped style.

For the look you are describing I think it is called `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! :) What I want to achieve is actually the style you see once you click one of your listed mail accounts in the Settings app, i.e. the page where you can edit host and user name and password etc. and this without leaving the page - a keyboard just slides up and the text in the table cell becomes editable. I do not see that described anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: If I understand you, read the section on "The Technique for Static Row Content". To see how to lay out that page.

Comment: Yes, I have been studying that section. I have a feeling that I would like to create the cell in my code instead in order to avoid depending on static label texts though. And in that case it is not that clear to me how to position the label and the text field. Well, guess I just have to understand more about bounds and frames or something!

Comment: Try this screencast http://pragmaticstudio.com/screencasts/5-custom-table-cells-in-interface-builder as it is a good overview. To accomplish your goal you just want to add a UITextField instead of a UILabel.

Comment: NICE!! Thank you! :) Hope I wont have to bother you again! ;D

Answer (score 0):

You need custom UITableViewCells and there are a number of ways of making them. For your purposes, any one of the techniques detailed in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) will probably suffice.

An alternative to those approaches is in [GSUtils](https://bitbucket.org/sbreatnach/gsutils/wiki/CustomView) (full disclosure: open-source library written by me), where you can use the same approach to designing your table view cells as you would design a UIView.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! :) As described below the above answer I am not able to find the style I want in the documentation... hmm...